# Uploading to EC2 CentOS instance using SublimeText SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, sublimetext2, sftp

I created an EC2 CentOS instance to host my php web app development version, I'm using Sublime Text as an IDE, and SFTP plugin to upload files directly then test.

Before, I was using SFTP with username/password/port 22 to connect

Now, I have the PEM file, and I already used it to install and configure some component. How can I connect using the PEM file and upload file via Sublime Text SFTP plugin?

I specified in sftp-config.json:

```
"ssh_key_file": "/home/USER/USER-EC-Virginia.pem",
```

but without any success, I get Connection timeout message.

Port 22 already allowed to receive traffic.

EDIT:
I tried to use PPK file with SublimeText and I'm still getting the same : Timeout error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're close...the following works for CentOS / RHEL on EC2

```
{
    "type": "sftp",
    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "host": "<your ec2 instance hostname>",
    "user": "<your username>",
    "remote_path": "<your remote path>",
    "connect_timeout": 30,
    "sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=~<path to .pem file>"]
}
```

You actually don't need to set `ssh_key_file": "/home/USER/USER-EC-Virginia.pem,`

Comment: If you're mapping a file to a remote server (right click -> ftp/sftp -> Map To Remote...) from the folder sidebar, it will generate an `sftp-config.json` file, the above configuration parameters will need to be updated in this file. Afterwards you can upload/download/diff/etc

Comment: Still getting the Timeout error even if I set sftp_flags, this is what I used : "sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=/home/user/name.pem"]

Comment: What are the permissions on the pem file? Per Amazon the pem file should be chmod 400. What is yours set to?

Comment: Woow man, I just changed the permissions to 0400 and its working. Thanks for saving my time. I was uploading to a dev vps then uploading the rev to EC2

Comment: Also make sure that "remote_path": "<your remote path>", corresponds to path for which user defined in "user" property of your SFTP configuration has access rights. Otherwise you will get permission denied.

Comment: @DarrenCato have you verified that you're able to sftp or scp to your Ubuntu server from outside of SublimeText? Are you successful from the command line?

Comment: @DarrenCato, please confirm that you can sftp and then post whatever error you're getting from sublime

Comment: "sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=/Users/username/xxx.pem"] will also work

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to One Bad Panda's comment, Please dont use these commands in Windows 7 to point to key file

```
"sftp_flags": ["-i /C/cygwin/home/Ehsan/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem"]

"sftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=/C/cygwin/home/Ehsan/.ssh/ekia_ec2.pem"]
```

instead use

```
"ssh_key_file": "C:/.../yourkey.ppk"
```